# WordPress can't write wp-config.php - triple-checked the permissions already

Tags: wordpress, nginx, file-permissions

Currently trying to set-up a new WordPress installation on our hardware. We're running Nginx and PHP 7.3 FPM and already run several other web instances under the same Nginx installation.

I've already tried every single combination in regards to file permissions (except for just 777ing everything - not looking forward to doing this), but I simply cannot get WordPress to be able to write files. This is what our configuration looks like:

Nginx runs as `www-data` (as configured in `nginx.conf`).

Several PHP FPM socks:

```
$ sudo ls /var/run/php/ -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     5 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm.pid
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm-w_app.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm-w_backend.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm-w_home.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm-w_rest.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 24 15:27 php7.3-fpm-w_webhook.sock
```

The one that runs the WordPress installation is `w_home`. Here's the FPM config in pool.d for it:

```
[w_home]
user = w_home
group = w_home
listen = /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-w_home.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

And finally, here's the Nginx configuration for this instance:

```
server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/sites/w_home/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name wp.***.de;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-w_home.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_sc$
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location @extensionless-php {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wp.***.de/fullchain$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wp.***.de/privk$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certb$
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = wp.***.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name wp.***.de;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I've already tried chowning the complete WordPress directory to www-data as well as nginx, as well as w_home. Every file is 644 (tried 664 as well), every directory 755. WordPress cannot write.

Any help?